# Javascript with PHP

Tags: php, javascript

I have an overlay image that is created in Javascript using the 'Createelement' function.  Now I would like to know if I can attach a handler to the mouseover event using PHP?

Can you give an example pls?

The image appears only when hovering over the element below it.

Regards,
T

**UPDATE**  I want to handle the mouseover event of that element with PHP on server side.  Just cause the whole site I'm editing is coded in PHP.  The problem is that all HTML/CSS & JS is generated by PHP code of this site, so I'm thinking using PHP will be easier.

What will the effects of that be on the user though, speed etc?

**UPDATE2**: So the image that I want to add this handler to, only appears when the mouse is hovered over the image below.  Now, when one then hovers over that hovering image, it flickers.  I'm trying to suppress the 'mouseover' event of that hovering image so it doesn't reload when hovered over, and so stops flickering.

Comment: please explain more clearly. you want the mouseover event to be handled in the browser using Javascript or on the server in PHP code ? if it's the latter you are going to need to write some ajax.

Comment: what do you want to do on mouse over?

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example:

```
var elem = document.createElement("…");
elem.onmouseover = function() {
    // your mouseover code
};
```

Answer (score 0):

PHP can't directly handle things that happen on the client side. So, to handle a mouseover w/ PHP, you have two options:

1) make an AJAX call on the mouseover event, handle it there.

or

2) have the PHP code echo javascript code.

if you can explain more clearly what you are trying to accomplish, that may help. one (or both) of these suggestions may not be applicable.

Comment: I have a website with an image gallery coded in PHP, which creates the entire HTML code for the browser.

The gallery has a series of images showing at the bottom & when an image is selected you see a big image at the top of the page.

It's on this big image I've put another image when hovering over it.  Now when this new image (hovering img) is gone over with mouse pointer, it flickers.  I'm trying to handle this flicker by blocking the mouseover - mouseout events of this hovering img. 

Make sense?

Comment: yes, but I am confused as to why you are trying to handle this with PHP. It's not possible. The closest you will get to that is echoing javascript code with PHP. Your best bet would be to do it in javascript.

Answer (score 0):

If your goal is to stop the overlay image from flickering, that can be achieved client-side (in JS) without any server-side work (in PHP).

If you provide a URL that demonstrates the flickering behavior, we'll have some chance of helping solve the problem.